# Counting subsets of points arranged in a cycle

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ points $P = p_1, ... ,p_n$ arranged in a cycle. Given parameters $1 \leq s \leq n$ and $1 \leq k \leq s$, how many subsets $S \subseteq P$ are there such that:

1. $|S|=s$.
2. The points of $S$ are arranged in exactly $k$ separate intervals along the cycle.

**Example:** if $n=10$, $s=6$ and $k=2$, we are asking how many six-point subsets $S$ there are in a cycle with ten points, such that the points of $S$ are arranged along two intervals. We can divide this into cases according to the lengths of the intervals.

**Case 1:** There could be an interval of length $1$ (an isolated point) and an interval of length $5$. In this case, there are 10 places to put the isolated point, and given a place for that point there are $3$ places to put the interval of length $5$, so altogether there are $30$ possibilities for this case.

The other cases can be handled in a similar fashion, and the total count is $75$.

This method seems to break down for higher values of $k$, though. To take a simple case, lets say that there are $3$ intervals and that the interval lengths are all $2$. It is no longer such a simple matter to count the possible arrangements of the intervals in this case.

So my question is: Is there a formula for the general case?

Comment: Let $C(n,s,k)$ denotes the number of all possibilities. About zero possibilities I guess there is the following two cases:

**Case 1:** If $s=n$ then $C(n,n,k)=\delta_{1,k}$;

**Case 2:** If $s<n$ then $C(n,s,k)=0$ if and only if $s+k>n$.

I also guess if $s+k\le n$ then $C(n,s,k)=C(n,n-s,k)$.